# Voltage and current while operating a Zener Diode

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, semiconductor-physics

While operating the Zener diode, even if there is a small change in the input voltage the current through the load resistance remains almost the same. Additionally, the current through the diode changes but the voltage across it essentially remains the same.
My question is simple-
Why so?

Comment: Can you share the full circuit you're asking about? (i.e. provide a schematic)

Comment: The answer to the question in your text is "because the zener diode has a very low differential resistance when operating in the zener mode of operation". But you tagged the question with `semiconductor-physics` which suggests you might actually want to know *why* it has a low differential resistance...can you edit to clarify?

Comment: I'm trying to provide an image but it keeps showing that the file size is too large. I'll keep trying, though.

Comment: Indeed, I want to know why it has a low differential resistance.

Comment: Have you read the WIkipedia article on the zener effect? Is there a particular part you don't understand?

Comment: I don't read from Wikipedia..it's too complex. I am just a high school student.